# MongoDB: mongoimport isodate on Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: json, mongodb, ubuntu, mongoimport, isodate

Platform: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit
Python installed, can't remember its version right now: I can update this question later

```
....$>sudo mongod --versiondb 
version v2.4.9 git 
git version: nogitversion

....$>sudo service mongodb status
start
```

My dbpath variable set on */etc/mongod.config* is equals to */home/utente/OFS/datasource*. I gave right permissions with chmod. From mongodb.log file I can see last line like:"*...waiting for connection on port 27017*"
Open a terminal, trying to import the json here below:

> { "_id":ObjectId("572f36bcb69df6b4280cee68"),
>   "formatoPreferito":ObjectId("57121b0d1dab7d841d149ed0"), "nome":"fra",
>   "cognome":"back", "dataNascita":ISODate("1987-09-17T22:00:00Z"),
>   "email":"test@test.com",
>   "password":"$2a$10$4LR/kFI.FHPXHug7Jo9z0.mSgFqT4j4ZMeM.x1MdBfp5HGAFCvdOG",
>   "ereader":"kindle",
>   "token":"$2a$10$WBT5.ylZiRkfSZM./7XUtemllTNN5jaJJy8KsVISvJTvUyUmP49ki",
>   "dataRegistrazione":ISODate("2016-05-08T12:53:15.262Z"), "attivo":true
>   }

With the command:

```
mongoimport --db ofs --collection utenti --host localhost --port 27017 --drop --file /home/utente/OFS/load.utenti.json
```

With the output:

> connected to: localhost:27017 
>   Tue May 24 00:04:27.151 dropping:
>   ofs.utenti 
>   Tue May 24 00:04:27.152 exception:BSON representation of
>   supplied JSON is too large: code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: **Bad
>   characters in value: offset:149** 
>   Tue May 24 00:04:27.152
>   Tue May 24 00:04:27.152 exception:BSON representation of supplied JSON is too large: code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Bad characters in value: offset:149 
>   Tue May 24 00:04:27.152 imported 0 objects 
>   Tue May 24 00:04:27.152 ERROR: encountered 2 error(s)s utente@utente-X551CAP:~/OFS$Tue May 24 00:04:27.152  Tue May 24 00:04:27.152 check 0 0

offset 149, watched on text editor, is the position of the ':' character on the **dataNascita** field. The --jsonArray parameter does not fix the errors. Question: is It something wrong with the json file or is It something wrong with ISODate data type and my version of mongodb? (it is not the mongodb-org software installed).

#### On Microsoft Windows 7

with a later mongodb version it seems all to work just fine:
[image: on Windows7 64 bit]

So now I am going back home, remove mongodb installed, install [later version](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community)  and update here.

Comment: Are you sure your file /home/utente/OFS/load.utenti.json contains only one json document? Because if you are using an array of documents, it is necessary to set the flag --jsonArray.

Comment: I am sure I tried with the json up here alone, and I tried copy/paste of it on a line below (changing the objid string value), and I tried with square once [{...},{...}] and without {...},{...}, I tried with _--jsonArray_ option and without it. The output is still the same. Thinking: json text file has to be **encoded** in specific - ex: _UTF-8_ ?

Comment: I look at your import data. It is written in BSON format, which is not mentioned in mongoimport doc. {$date:"1987-09-17T22:00:00Z"} is the format for ISODate. P.S. Try http://mongobooster.com, a MongoDB GUI, easy to import and export.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns the installation was not successfully ended. **I installed the same mongodb version one time again.**
As soon as the installation ended, I was able to run successfully the mongoimport command with the ISODate objects inside the json input file.